# Vue instance per component over single instance

Tags: vue.js

due to the structure of our websites we currently are unable to create one main `app` instance, as there is too much HTML within this.

So instead we are currently looking for the class of `app` and then creating a new Vue instance per component, which isn't great for communicating between components but it's our current work around.

We are working to create a new structure to support just one overall `app`. However, just wondering if creating a new instance of Vue for each component is bad for browser performance over having just one instance with the component inside this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer: No

There won’t be any performance difference between an app that uses a root Vue component with child components and an app that uses multiple root Vue components.

All components are still just Vue instances - so it isn’t any different. The only difference is the organization and usage of the instances.